# docker build pipeline failure

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cicd

docker build not work

script{sh 'docker build -t devopsmydockerhub/spring-k8s .'}

ERROR: error during connect: Get "https://docker:2376/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

how can declare correct pipeline All other codes work fine. I tried many ways but this is only the problem

Comment: Sounds like DNS is resolving `docker` to `127.0.0.11`, but that host isn't available. Only you could tell us why.